# Specific source of narayana upanishad

Tags: resource

It is known that this is from Krishna yajurvedam
It is not clear as to the exact source like which aranyaka.. which samhita..
this post is to know if some one can tell the exact source of narayana Upanishad from the Krishna yajurvedam